# Two users and two tables one lgin using yii2

Tags: yii2-user

I have a Assignment to do. my DB has two tables, one for Tutor another one for users. users table is used to login to the system as student. and same goes for Tutor table. up to now students can login. but can't login Tutor.

When I'm entering Tutor login details it goes to users login. this Assignment is kind of Student feedback portal. using Yii2.
Can i do something by using 'switchIdentity()' or loginByCookie()?

Comment: You Can Use `AccessControl` Filter and provide appropriate `rules` in it

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but access control can use to differentiate the users. I don't want to do that for now. my tables have different fields for two users. students do not need Tutor registration form details when register. tutor do not need student registration details when register. when tutor login his login details should collect from Tutor table. (email and hash password) same goes for the student table.

Comment: It's best to use a SIngle `users` table which must have some roles like 'student,teacher' and both table Student,Tutor have userId foreignKey

Comment: one thing i don't understand is if i want different fields when register the student and tutor how could i achieve by this only using one table?  let's say student registration have 'fname, laname, email, password' fields. tutor registration have 'fullname, academic year, module, email, pasword' fields.